# Generating an Alphabet Sequence in Java

Tags: java, string, iterator

I am beginning at programing and I have an assignment to generate Alphabet sequence. In constructor we have an input, every time  when call the method next() will return the next value in the sequence.

```
"","a","b","c",....."z","A","B",......"Z","aa","bb",.....,"zz",.....
if input is:
If the current string is:"z",so after calling next(),we get "A";
If the current string is:"Z",so after calling next(),we get "aa";
If the current string is:"az",so after calling next(),we get "ba";
If the current string is:"ZZZZZZ",so after calling next(),we get "aaaaaaa";
```

code assignmnet is here:

```java
import  java.util.Iterator;

public class StringIterator implements Iterator<String> {

    //Complete the following methods
    public StringIterator(String start){
        // task 0
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Delete this line and implement this function");
    }

    public boolean hasNext(){
        // task 0
        //assume string length()<Integer. MAX_VALUE
       return true;
    }
    public String next(){
        // task 0
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Delete this line and implement this function");
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you having difficulty with for your assignment? It may help to read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) to refine your question so we can help you.

Comment: i don't know how to generate the next sequnce and how to  write code that works for every input

Comment: Do you know how to go from `"a"` to `"b"`? Why not start there.

Answer (score 0):

The idea: prepare a String A with your alphabet: "abc...ABC..Z", and prepare a "increase" function that, given a char inside A, returns the following one.

The initialiser sets the original string in a variable "s"; then the next() gets "s", checks the last character, and invokes the "increase" function on that char. Then replace the last character of the string with the result. But... if the new char is the first of A, then you need to "increase" also the next char in "s", etc. Until you reach the end of the string: in this case, simply add the first char of the alphabet.

You can do a recursive function for that if you are able to do it. Otherwise, you can use an index "i" initialised to the string length and move it back of one position whenever you need to get the previous char in the string.

```
/**
 *
 */
package it.mixedstuff;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;;

/**
 * @author samuele m.
 *
 */
public class StringIterator implements Iterator<String>
{
    private static final String A = "abcABC";
    private String s;

    // Complete the following methods
    public StringIterator(String start)
    {
        s = start;
    }

    private char increase(char c)
    {
        int k = A.indexOf(c);
        if (k == -1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unsupported char");
        }
        k = (k + 1) % A.length();
        return A.charAt(k);
    }

    private char firstChar()
    {
        return A.charAt(0);
    }

    private boolean isFirst(char ch)
    {
        return (ch == firstChar());
    }

    public boolean hasNext()
    {
        return A.length() < Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }

    public String next()
    {
        if (!hasNext()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        int i = s.length();
        while (--i >= 0) {
            // get char at position A[i]
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            // return the following one
            c = increase(c);
            // replace the char in the string
            s = s.substring(0, i) + c + s.substring(i + 1);
            // have we ended?
            if (!isFirst(c)) {
                return s;
            }
        }
        // if string is ended, we need to add the first char
        if (i < 0) {
            s = firstChar() + s;
        }
        return s;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String base = "Bc";
        StringIterator s = new StringIterator(base);
        System.out.println("We start with " + base);
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            String n = s.next();
            System.out.println("Then there is " + n);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thavk u  this is work!!!!

Comment: i understand what i missed after seeing your sokution,THANKS:)